# Before the IAU, what was the international governing body for naming astronomical bodies?

Tags: astronomy, naming-conventions

Today, the commonly recognized authority on the naming of astronomical bodies is the [International Astronomical Union (IAU)](http://www.iau.org/). It was created in 1919, and quickly rose to a position of prominence within the astronomical community.

Before the creation of the IAU, what body (if any) was considered the leading international organization for astronomical naming?